# One div overlay another - same size and position but div doesn't completely cover the underlying one

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty sure this is a bug as it only happens on certain machines running Chrome, but I have two divs, each 500px by 500px in a container, the second absolutely positioned so it sits on the top of the first and is supposed to cover it completely.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='jprt-hover'></div>
  <div class="jprt-hoveroverlay"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
}

.jprt-hover{
  background-color:#000;
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
}

.jprt-hoveroverlay{
  background-color:#FFF;
  position: absolute;
  height:500px;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mh04qz3r/1/

Results may vary on your machine, so please see this screenshot: [image]

If you look at the right and left side, you can see a thin line exposing the black div behind it.  On the site I am working on, all 4 sides of the box have that thin line.  It's very subtle, but I'm curious if this is something that happens often and if any of you know of any resolutions for it (besides making the overlay div slightly bigger than the underlying one).

Thanks!

Comment: I am not seeing this in Chrome, Safari, or Firefox so I can't offer much in the way of suggestion. However, since both child `divs` have the same dimensions as the parent, change them to `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` and see if that changes anything for you.

Comment: @samurai_jane Actually the original code had height,width set to 100%.  I figured there could more variation there in the way the browser calculates it, so I made it explicit to 500px :(